# jQuery.noConflict() breaks plugin

Tags: jquery

I use both Prototype and jQuery in my rails app. To resolve the `$` conflict I do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

This works mostly fine, but I am trying to use [a plugin](http://simplesli.de) that does not like it and throws a `$ is not a function type` error.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Why are you using both prototype and jQuery?  That is, what does prototype provide, which jQuery does not?  (Or, the other way around, but you want to use a jQuery plugin. So, I'd assume jQuery is a higher priority.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhg. Some functions for simpleslide use a jquery wrapping technique to protect its internal use of $ and other functions do not.

It's only a couple of top level functions with the exposure problem (as near as I can tell), so you could add the protective wrappers yourself and/or ask the author for a fix.

Answer (score 8):

Try the following

```
(function ($){
    /* plugin code */
})(jQuery);
```

This is creating a function and executing it right away passing `jQuery` as a param named `$`. Meaning `$` would work as jQuery only inside this scope.

Since the plugin have internal methods that uses `$` the best would be to ask for a fix, or fix by yourself changing any `$` that is a problem for `jQuery`.

Comment: I saw that, but when I use that technique, the plugin throws an error, the main set up function i.e. simpleSlide();, becomes unrecognized.

Comment: Could there be a loading issue..this is how I load it now..
<script type="text/javascript" src="bb/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

 
    
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.simpleSlide_min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
  </script>

Comment: when are you loading prototype?