# Magento add to cart doesnt work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

Hello i have a problem with my add to cart button in my magento theme. i have changed all theme, but it doesnt work, please any can help me? i see in the console the error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined gabinete-ice-2x24w-magg.html:220
onclick
```

but too appear error in my prototype.js im put here the file prototype.js, and here the live link http://masluz.panamerik.net/gabinete-ice-2x24w-magg.html i hope can help me guys thanks!

PROTOTYPE.JS LINK:
http://masluz.panamerik.net/js/prototype/prototype.js

When i go to checkout page to place the order have error too with prototype.js whats happend with this?

Comment: You seem to have a jQuery conflict or some other issue  with cloud-zoom.1.0.2.min.js:9 .. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882374/how-do-i-implement-jquery-noconflict or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217414/jquery-noconflict-breaks-plugin

Comment: Thanks i solved it, i have called 2 jquery.js in the same file its is the cause of the error thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are callling two copies of jQuery, this will cause all sorts of issues with Magento.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://masluz.panamerik.net/js/megamenu/jquery-1-7-2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://masluz.panamerik.net/js/iwd/all/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using multiple version of jquery (1.7.2, 1. 1.10.2 and lastly 1.3.2). Since the last loaded version is 1.3.2 it is very much outdated and will not support many functions.

Also, you are loading jquery.noconflict file before your last jquery include, hence the errors are most likely because of the conflict issues.

You can try removing all other version of jquery and load noconflict.js file at the end of all the scripts.