# Modifying jQuery $ function to support legacy code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I joined stackoverflow, because it's been a great help to me over the years, I'm pretty good at JavaScript, and I saw some questions I could contribute to.

I quickly found out how ubiquitous jQuery is on stackoverflow, so I decided to learn it.  My first thought was, *Wowzers!*

I've been using my own dollar sign function, which is simply:

```
function $(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

I know I can redefine jQuery's $ function by using `noConflict()`.

However, I'd like to keep it in case `noConflict()` breaks any jQuery plugins, and because I'd like my code to be easily maintainable after my upcoming retirement.

The problem is that I have tens of thousands of instances of `$(...)` throughout my code.

I've come up with a method that I *think* will allow me to use jQuery's $ function without breaking my own code:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

function $(id, context) {
  var r= document.getElementById(id);
  return !r || context ? jQuery(id, context) : r;
}
```

Example at http://jsfiddle.net/0nxn3fd5/1/

I rarely use tag names as ids, and I would stop doing so altogether for any new code I write.  This just seems like a quick way for me to incorporate jQuery into existing code.

Is there a problem with this approach?

Comment: jQuery has methods accessed like `$.get`, so you prevent yourself from those

Comment: I don't know why some of these answers have been downvoted.  Any response is appreciated.

Comment: `$.noConflict();` must not break plugins, or at least only those badly-written ones that you wouldn't use anyway.

Comment: @Jakub, that's a really strong argument.  I can re"get" it by adding `$.get= jQuery.get`.  But I wonder how many other jQuery methods I'd need to do like this.

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi.  I had found an old stackoverflow regarding a plugin that does break using `$.noConflict()`.  So I wasn't sure how frequently that occurred:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217414/jquery-noconflict-breaks-plugin

Comment: @RickHitchcock: I see. Well-written plugins use the [(offical)](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#protecting-the-alias-and-adding-scope) wrapper from BrunoLM's answer. It shouldn't occur at all :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two concerns I would have using that.

1. You are potentially querying the DOM twice for each jQuery call. Additional, unnecessary load.
2. You could still have compatibility issues with jQuery dependent modules. What document.getElementById() returns is not the same as what jQuery returns (a jQuery object). So if a library used $("#element") and gets a document element back instead of a jQuery object, there likely would be an error.

I wouldn't recommend the solution. Instead, why not do a find and replace for $( prior to including jQuery?

Comment: #1 is a very valid point.  I had considered this but decided that it would be a minor cost given the convenience.

Comment: I'm not so sure about #2.  My $ function would return getElementById only if there was an existing id by that name.  Therefore, it would be operating on legacy code, which doesn't make any jQuery calls.

Comment: An example of #2 would be if you named an ID the same as a tag name. For example, if you selected #("form") and you HTML page had an element with #form and a form tag, you would end up with the ID, not the tag. In addition, the other jQuery methods that Jakub Michalek mentioned in the comments is a concern. Many libraries will be using $.ajax and other similar methods.

Comment: As I incorporate jQuery into my own code, I think I would catch any  instances of IDs being equal to tag names during testing.  However, this might bite my replacement when I retire, so it is certainly a valid point.

Comment: I think that (retirement/replacement) is really the biggest factor. If someone steps into a site and see's jQuery they make the assumption it is a standard implementation of jQuery. If they attempt to use $.ajax or select an ID/Tag name that they will encounter very puzzling issues.

Answer (score 0):

Given the upcoming retirement, the question is of how much you care about the developers who will take over from you. There are tools that can help you rename your old $() function. @Jason mentions find/replace, and that would most likely be sufficient. If not, there are tools like Facebook's [jsgrep](https://github.com/facebookarchive/jsgrep) that may help. The repo is archived, but I shouldn't imagine that the tool should therefore stop working.

Comment: upcoming retirement of jQuery, I assume? Please source the claim.

Comment: @Tom was referring to my own upcoming retirement.

Comment: It's a bit overwhelming updating 1,500+ files, but this may be my best bet.

Comment: @Jason, given that this has been explained, would you mind removing the down vote?

Comment: I would...but it wasn't me. And I do disagree with the down vote.

Comment: Oh, apologies! Would the down voter (if they see this) mind explaining?

Comment: @Tom, you actually got two down votes, and they both may have been due to the misunderstanding re "retirement."  I voted you up, but that still leaves you down one.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use jQuery(...) instead of $(...)? Sure, it's a little bit longer. But what else is copy pasta for?

Comment: I don't think copy/paste will help while I'm typing code.  I was thinking of redefining `jQuery` as simply `j`, but that could screw up loop variables.